# xna remove graphics window during execution

Tags: c#, xna

Since i wont be using graphics for my application, i was wondering how can i remove the xna window that always appears during execution. I have tried to comment out everything related to graphics and the window still pops up.

many thanks.

Comment: what would your purpose for that be for? An XNA game definitely would have to show some graphics. If you're not making a game, then why create an XNA project?

Comment: @maruris To use other non-graphical features of the XNA library in a non-game application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XNA `Game` class and, in fact, the entire `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll` assembly is optional in XNA. To ***not*** use it, you could either:

1) Remove your game class (the class in your project derived from `Game`) and the code that uses it in `Program.cs`. Replace it with whatever interface code you want to use instead. You could then remove the reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll` if you are not using anything from it.

OR

2) Create a new project of your desired type. Then add references to your desired XNA assemblies to that project. Note that this project will not be able to contain XNA Content Project References directly (you can use an "XNA Game Library" project as a go-between).

Note that by not using `Game` many things in XNA will not work unless you provide your own implementation of some of the services that `Game` normally provides. For example you can't use anything graphics-related (eg: `Texture2D`) without a `GraphicsDevice` - so you have to create one yourself.

You also need to call `FrameworkDispatcher.Update()` regularly (normally `Game` calls it once per frame) for various things - particularly audio playback - to work properly.